# Cannot use ParseLoginUI along with the Parse SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

In my project I'm using the Parse SDK and now i want to add the ParseLoginUI library from here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

I imported the library into my eclipse but i cannot use it inside my project.

Every time i try to include it as a library to my project, it gives me this error

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parse.jar file in the Parse SDK and in the login library are different versions.  You can replace one with the other, and everything should work fine (found in the 'lib' folder).  If you're using gradle to build the project, you'll need to appropriately adjust the dependencies config.

I will note that the Login UI library comes with no associated JavaDocs (and it's behind the SDK .jar by one version), so if you don't want to lose the convenient access to the docs, you should replace the .jar file in the login library with the one from the SDK, and not vice versa.

Alternatively, you can remove the parse.jar completely from you main project, and it will draw it from the loginUI library.